# Why is Magento licensed under two different licenses?

Tags: magento-ce, licensing

Recently noticed that both Magento 1 and Magento 2 have two different licenses files:

- `LICENSE.txt` which is the OSL License
- `LICENSE_AFL.txt` which is the AFL License

However, the `LICENSE.html` only shows the OSL license.

What is the point of having two different licenses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the less restrictive AFL is used for templates to make paid themes (and extensions) possible with adjusted base templates.

Comment: Do you know if that is actually documented anywhere?

Comment: @Nick no, but I searched again and this is the most official I found is this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79724/copyright-notice-on-modified-base-default-template-in-own-design-package